# set log level in launch file

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a way to set the log level for a node in a launch file?

I would find this practical.

Cheers,
Gaël

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/197964/set-log-level-in-launch-file/) by [galou](https://answers.ros.org/users/14171/galou/) on ROS Answers with karma: 265 on 2014-11-21

Post score: 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Self answer: http://wiki.ros.org/rosconsole#Configuration

The feature is not launch-file specific and works by setting an environment variable to a configuration file.

---

Originally posted by [galou](https://answers.ros.org/users/14171/galou/) with karma: 265 on 2015-02-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2015-02-16**:
Please mark your answer as correct.

**Comment by [galou](https://answers.ros.org/users/14171/galou/) on 2015-09-11**:
Actually, my own answer seems to work only for roscpp node.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Combining [calling rosservice in launch file](https://answers.ros.org/question/11271/call-a-service-at-startup-with-a-launch-file/?answer=15041#post-id-15041) and [setting log level with rosservice](https://answers.ros.org/question/241179/rosconsole-debug-logger-how-to-use-it/), the launch-file specific way would be the following

```
<node pkg="rosservice" type="rosservice" name="set_move_base_log_level" args="call --wait /move_base/set_logger_level 'ros.move_base' 'debug'" />
```

I wouldn't be surprised if there's a proper launch file specific way of doing this... if someone knows, please enlighten us!

---

Originally posted by [Rufus](https://answers.ros.org/users/34739/rufus/) with karma: 1083 on 2020-04-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 12

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2021-09-14**:
Sometimes a `rosnode cleanup` is required prior to the launch that contains this, otherwise the `--wait` results in this (at least in noetic)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/rospy/impl/tcpros_service.py", line 152, in wait_for_service
    uri = contact_service(resolved_name)
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/rospy/impl/tcpros_service.py", line 113, in contact_service
    s.connect(addr)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
...
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/rospy/rostime.py", line 190, in get_rostime
    raise rospy.exceptions.ROSInitException("time is not initialized. Have you called init_node()?")
rospy.exceptions.ROSInitException: time is not initialized. Have you called init_node()?
```